# Every man has one

Tags: riddle

Married men give theirs to their wives.
Koreans tend to have short ones.
Many Germans have long ones.
The current US President has a longer one than his predecessor.
Popes rarely use theirs.

This should be easy, but please keep your mind out of the gutter!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is

> Surnames (though there are probably some men without them)

Married men give theirs to their wives.

> Many wives (in Western cultures, at least) take the husband's surname in marriage

Koreans tend to have short ones.

> Romanized Korean names ("Gim/Kim", "Pa[r]k", "Li/Lee/Rhee", "Choi" are some popular last names) are often very short

Many Germans have long ones.

> German surnames can be long, as German lends itself to long compound words

The current US President has a longer one than his predecessor.

> Obama is longer, by one letter, than Bush

Popes rarely use theirs.

> Popes usually take a Pope Name, like "Innocent" or "Pius" or "Gregory"